# Magnific popup jumps

Tags: jquery, css, magnific-popup

Can someone explain to me why magnific popup jumps on my website:

http://fagardesigns.com/portfolio

and not on this website created from a template for a friend:

http://felixplakolb.com/portfolio

In both cases roll over an image and click the search icon.

In the documentation I found the following:
http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#known-issues

However implementing that 'fix' did absolutely nothing. Hence, I am wondering what is inherently different between the two websites that is causing it to not jump in the second example. I have tried setting `overflow-y:scroll` in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, perhaps it might be helpful to others:

For some reason magnific does stuff to the html tag, in my stylesheet I had the following (not necessary) code. Removing it fixed the jumping.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You answered yourself within 4 minutes!

Comment: indeed, was lucky I guess!